# GNU linker script to create extra space in ELF file before the first section

Tags: linux, linker

I need to create some empty space between program header tables and the first section of an ELF file. 
Currently I am using this script which assumes that .interp and .hash are the first 2 sections. (This assumption is true for my current environment)

```
SECTIONS
{
  . += 0x600 ;
  .interp   : { *(.interp) }
}
INSERT BEFORE .hash
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this without making assumptions about the section layout.

Comment: What would be this first section? Can't you just add in on top of a known section, such as `.text`?